# Container Build error - failed to shutdown container - container encountered an error during Shutdown

Tags: docker, dockerfile, vmware, docker-for-windows, docker-build

I am trying to build container image in windows 2019 standard edition.  The server run in VMware environment.  While performing docker build by using docker file received following error

**returned a non-zero code: 4294967295: failed to shutdown container: container 3bdxxxxx encountered an error during Shutdown: failure in a Windows system call: The interface is unknown. (0x6b5)**

Docker Info

```
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Standard Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.1282)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 6GiB
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Docker Vesion

```
 Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Built:             11/13/2019 08:00:16
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

 Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
 Version:          19.03.5
 API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
 Built:            11/13/2019 07:58:51
 OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
 Experimental:     false
```

In the docker file, I am using

- FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
- PowerShell command to install windows feature
- start-process command to start application EXE

Receiving above error while executing "start-process"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue due to multiple reasons,  Did following changes to fix

- Increased CPU cores (The CPU reaches 100% while performing docker build operation,  Due to this container got exit in between).
- While performing docker build used the "**--memory=16g**" parameter. Refer to [Runtime options with Memory, CPUs, and GPUs for more details](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/).
- Application EXE expecting reboot configured "**/noreboot**" in the configuration.